# Android Studio: Please Select Project SDK - What does this mean?

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm importing [this project](https://github.com/mhsjlw/AndroidSnap) from Github into Android Studio 2.1.2. I'm at a point where it's asking me "Please select project SDK. This SDK will be used by default by all project modules." There are 2 options - "1.7" or "Android API 23 Platform". How do I know which one to pick? The "1.7" option has a ton of files while the other has only 2 files.

My overall goal is to just open this project and learn from it. I wanted to look at the source code for a functioning project that is not as simple as the tutorials given for Android Studio. I wanted a bit more complexity.

Comment: Both have the necessary compilers. You should pick Java 1.7, though, because then you don't need to worry about changing API versions of the app

Answer (score 1):

That means you probably haven't configured Android Studio. YOu have to install Android SDK in order for everything to work.

I cannot find the raw SDK download link, so you probably have to use Android Studio to download it.

Also, you should download Java 8 to get all functionality of Android Studio 2.1.2(Android Studio 2.x requires java 8(or higher)) so selecting 1.7 is probably for compatability mode

Comment: Studio comes with an SDK installer, though

Comment: That's the alternative, but if it doesn't work the link above is the alternative

Comment: You gave the link to Studio, not the SDK

Comment: Doesn't address the key question: "How do I know which one to pick?"

Comment: @SMBiggs: "Also, you should download Java 8 to get all functionality of Android Studio 2.1.2(Android Studio 2.x requires java 8(or higher)) so selecting 1.7 is probably for compatability mode"

Comment: @Zoe  Yes, I read your original answer several times.  But I STILL DON'T KNOW WHICH ONE TO PICK!  You STILL haven't answered the question!  What are the benefits and problems with the two choices: "1.7" or "Android API 23 Platform"?  And what does Java 8 have to do with making this choice?  Are you saying that if I install Java 8, I won't have this choice any more?

Comment: @SMBiggs Ngl, I haven't touched Android in ages (personally super happy about that choice). Just try something. Pick one, see what happens - the world isn't gonna spontaneously combust if you pick one that doesn't work for your project. The worst that can happen is that you have to re-pick the SDK or re-create the project. Generally, if you're in doubt, just try. The vast majority of the time (in this specific field - low-level situations are different), picking the wrong option is reversible, or at least possible to re/un-do